# jQuery Mobile - Splitting a page into 4 Parts

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I`m using jQuery mobile and I want to split the page into four parts([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CRSVU/)) with header and footer enabled. But somehow it is not working here.. [My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cdbxc/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.2/jquery.mobile-1.1.2.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.2/jquery.mobile-1.1.2.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css"/>
    </head>



    <body>
        <div data-role="page">
            <div data-role="header" data-rel="back">

            </div>

            <div id="div1" class="a"></div>
            <div id="div2" class="a"></div>
            <div id="div3" class="a"></div>
            <div id="div4" class="a"></div>

            <div data-role="footer">
                <h4>Page Footer</h4>
            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
```

CSS

```
html, body { height: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0; }
div.a { width: 50%; height: 50%; float: left; }
#div1 { background: #DDD; }
#div2 { background: #AAA; }
#div3 { background: #777; }
#div4 { background: #444; }
```

I can see only footer, but that too at the top. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Hmm... the fiddle you provided seems okay. I see the page in four parts. Can you give the fiddle with problems?

Comment: Here it is http://jsfiddle.net/Cdbxc/

Comment: Can you fix the Fiddle please? JSFiddle doesn't actually know where 'app.css' is. You have to paste that into the CSS box.

Comment: The fiddle is also freaking out because he copy/pasted the page, rather than using the left panel for the libraries and such.

Answer (score 2):

Use jQM grids layout.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/mdmvh/)**

```
<div class="ui-grid-a">
  <div id="div1" class="ui-block-a">A1</div>
  <div id="div2" class="ui-block-b">B1</div>
  <div id="div3" class="ui-block-a">A2</div>
  <div id="div4" class="ui-block-b">B2</div>
</div>
```

Resource: [Grids](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/widgets/grids/)

Answer (score 0):

You also need to set `height: 100%;` to your main parent div

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Cdbxc/1/)

In the demo if you remove height: 100%; from main div then it won't work.